# 'WordBundle' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#

I feel like this is probably a really dumb oversight on my part, but I can't see why I'm getting the error that my constructor doesn't take 2 arguments. It looks like it does to me, I think I'm using the right class and namespace names, after reading it repeatedly and searching similar answers on here I can't figure it out. Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

MODEL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WordCounter.Models
{
    public class WordBundle
    {
        private string _wordInput;
        private string _sentenceInput;

        public WordBundle (string wordInput, string sentenceInput)
        {
            _wordInput = wordInput;
            _sentenceInput = sentenceInput;
        }

    }
}
```

TEST:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using WordCounter.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WordCounter.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class WordBundleTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void WordBundleConstructor_CreatesInstanceOfWordBundle_WordBundle()
        {
            string testWord = "cat";
            string testSentence = "Who let the cat out of the cathedral?";
            WordBundle newWordBundle = new WordBundle(testWord, testSentence);
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(WordBundle), newWordBundle.GetType());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code is right, i can't see any errors

Comment: Sometimes, the Visual Studio show inexistent errors, because of the cache crashes. Try restart Visual Studio or restart your PC.

Comment: try to clean the solution and rebuild it also

Comment: fyi the assert is meaninless there.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after getting more eyes on the project, it looks like I have a conflict with a classname in another file and that was hijacking my constructor call. Thanks for taking a look, João!

Comment: The advise is to always make a "minimal, complete, verifiable example" when doing so. If you had done so, you would propably have noticed the difference quicker. That is just one reason that is a "advised/required thing to do".